# Can I change the text of a label in a masterpage when loading a content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a label in a master page (sample.master) called lblHeading.

I want to dynamically change the text of the label when I load the content page.

I need to do this because I want to change the heading to something meaningful but only after I know about the content of the page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

You want to create a [strongly-type master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) and you can then access it's properties from your content page during Page_Load or wherever else.

Answer (score 16):

yes, you can in this very simple way........

```
((Label)Master.FindControl("lblHeading")).Text = "your new text";
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. `MasterPage` behaves just like `UserControl` in your page.

Possible steps to implement this:

1. Create a property or method on the MasterPage that enables you to make changes to the Label. E.g.:

   ```
   public void ChangeLabel(string label) {
     lblHeading.Text = label;
   }
   ```
2. From your `Page`, get the reference to the `MasterPage` by using the `Page.Master` property.
3. Call the method defined in step 1 to change the `MasterPage` contents.

Additional info: You may need to cast `Page.Master` into your `MasterPage` type, try [Coding the Wheel's link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) for instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Eg, from your page do this (master page has label with ID="Label_welcome"):

    Label mpLabel = (Label)Page.Master.FindControl("Label_welcome");

      if (mpLabel != null)
      {
        mpLabel.Text = "Welcome Fazio!";
      }

Answer (score 3):

Do as stated above. Then, e.g., from your page do this (master page has label with ID="Label_welcome"):

```
Label mpLabel = (Label)Page.Master.FindControl("Label_welcome");

  if (mpLabel != null)
  {
    mpLabel.Text = "Welcome Fazio!";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a public property in the masterpage that will change the label.

```
public string Heading
{
    set 
    {
        lblHeading.text = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on how deep your controls inside the Master page are. In my case, I had a Label control inside a ContentPlaceHolder control... so I had to do this...

```
Label myLBL = this.Master.FindControl("HeaderContent").FindControl("myLabel") as Label;
```