# Changing Labels Text on MasterPage file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi im unable to change the Text properties of my labels that are on the MasterPage and I don't know todo it this is what I've come up with but it doesn't work. It finds the control but doesn't change the text any ideas.

```
    MasterPage master = Page.Master;
    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender popup1 = 
        master.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1") as AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender;
    Label lblMessage = master.FindControl("lblMessage") as Label;
    lblMessage.Text = msg;       
    Label MessageStatus = master.FindControl("lblMessageStatus") as Label;
    MessageStatus.Text = msgStatus;        
    popup1.Show();
```

Comment: When is your code being run in your content page (e.g. Page_Init, Page_Load, etc)

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149680/can-i-change-the-text-of-a-label-in-a-masterpage-when-loading-a-content-page

Comment: I would presume that it is because you are using the AjaxControlToolKit, are the controls on the popup? Perhaps you should interact with them from there rather?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you trying to do but you can create a public setter and getter for the label like this on master page

```
     public string label1Text 
        { 
         get
         { 
         return Label1.Text; 
         } 
         set 
         {
        Label1.Text = value; 
         }
        }
```

and then call it from content page like this

```
Site myMasterPage = Page.Master as Site; 
myMasterPage.label1Text ="text to display";
```

Comment: What is Site which type I can't use site for some reason

Comment: a way to call the master page not sure how you do in in your project you can use your way  MasterPage master = Page.Master;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check for null.

```
Label MessageStatus =  Master.FindControl("lblMessageStatus") as Label ;
if(MessageStatus !=null)
{
MessageStatus.Text = "Your text here"; 

}
```